# $\tan(A/2)\tan(B/2)$ in terms of $r , s,$ and $R$

Tags: geometry

I want to know as many as possible identities that involve
$r, R, s$ and $\tan(A/2)$, $\tan(B/2)$, and $\tan(C/2)$ in a triangle for proving a geometric inequality, where $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle, $R$ is the radius of the circumscribe circle, $s$ is the semiperimeter of the $\triangle{ABC}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about the law of cotangents. It states that [for a triangle whose one angle is $A$ and the side opposite $a$ and so on]:

$$\frac{\cot(A/2)}{s-a} = \frac{\cot(B/2)}{s-b} = \frac{\cot(C/2)}{s-c} = \frac{1}{r}$$

You can very easily relate $\cot(A/2)$ and $\tan(A/2)$ and so on. If you want the proof, then ask me.

Now, some other identities you may derive by manipulating the above law, for eg. multiplying the three expressions above.